# Prevent Update Trigger From Firing After Insert Trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I have a MariaDB 10.5 database with a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that is getting triggered after a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger which is causing problems for me.

Is there a way I can prevent the `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger from triggering after the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger?

Here are both triggers:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER HASH_NAMES_BEFORE_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT ON items
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.name = SHA2(NEW.name, 256);
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER HASH_NAMES_BEFORE_UPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE ON items
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.name = SHA2(NEW.name, 256);
```

Comment: Triggers fire when update or insert events occur so what are you doing?

Comment: @P.Salmon I know but the update trigger fires when I do an insert. I want to make it so it only fires when I perform an update and not an update/insert.

Comment: Can you show an example of the INSERT that causes the UPDATE trigger to fire? This can happen if you use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but otherwise not.

Comment: @BillKarwin the insert query looks something like this: `INSERT INTO items (name, desc, value) VALUES ("Item 1", "An example item.", 50)`

Comment: That insert will not cause both triggers to fire, there must be something else happening.

Comment: Why do you think both triggers are firing?

Comment: By the way, 10.5 is a MariaDB version, not MySQL. MariaDB is a different product from MySQL, even though MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, both products have been changing since then. You should not think of them as compatible anymore.

Comment: @P.Salmon actions of both triggers are performed when doing an insert.

Comment: If you add a write to a debug table and fix the code errors there it's clear that your assertion is incorrect https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=993d88d60c617360e5b2942fc4b2baad

Comment: @P.Salmon that was it! Thanks a lot for your comment & examples! I suggest that you convert your comment to an answer.